# How to compile PHP extensions cross-version?

Tags: php, linux, compilation

How to compile a PHP extension that will work on every version of PHP as well as every version of Linux?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to compile it once for every platform (a Windows library won't run on GNU/Linux, just as well as a 64-bit library won't run in a 32-bit environment). If this is what you are trying to do, the answer is: it's impossible.

Comment: i write a simple c code from http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021
that i compile it in centos (i have php 5.1.2 in my centos).
now how can i compile it that can run in debian (in another version of php) ?
both of centos and debian is 34-bit

Comment: @red: 34-bit? But seriously, you can't, several distributions will use different libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to create a "compatible with everything" binary package.

To allow for maximum compatibility I'd recommend that you package the file in a tarball with a `package.xml` file in the same way that PECL packages are distributed. This would allow someone to easily compile/install the package anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible - its not even possible in java

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a similar question and was given a very sensible suggestion:

[How to build a PHP extension that runs in many PHP versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727630/how-to-build-a-php-extension-that-runs-in-many-php-versions/24119583?iemail=1&noredirect=1#24119583)