# How to build a PHP extension that runs in many PHP versions?

Tags: php, c++

I have created a PHP extension using C++. I want to ship my extension to my clients in its binary form. That means I need to build a separate version of it for each PHP version (5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5) and each processor architecture.

My questions are:

1. why do they keep updating the API timestamp while the API itself seemingly does not change?  Wouldn't it remove a lot of headache while upgrading your system to use the next version of PHP?  Just for comparison, I also have a version of my extension for MS Excel using the XLL API and that API has remained backwards compatible since 2003 which allows me to have just two binaries (32 and 64 bit) for all of my clients.
2. Is there any way around this problem?  I.e. is there a way to build a PHP extension that can be run in multiple PHP versions?

Comment: There is a simple solution: Don't distribute it as a binary file. It would ALSO make it more reasonable for people to install. Unless you work for a large software company that is trusted, I certainly wouldn't just take a binary PHP extension without knowing that it doesn't contain anything that, for example, send all the username/password entries into my server back to your server...

Comment: I agree with @Mats - create a make package that your clients can run. If this is not possible, you could create an automated build system that cross-compiles for each arch and version, and pushes the binaries to your download site.

Comment: @halfer, could you expand a bit more on how I would go about creating such a system? Would that involve having multiple php5-dev versions installed on the build machine? I am building on (and for) Linux btw.

Comment: What makes you think that "the API does not change"? Some rather significant changes have taken place in the versions you're describing.

Comment: That was a guess on my part and apparently an incorrect one.  Anyway, I'm not so much interested in the "Why" part of my question but I'd be very keen to hear any suggestions on solving this.  At this point my "cross compiler" comprises of a few virtual machines with Debian 6 and 7 of the two bitnesses each. Any thoughts on how this can be done in a fully automated way?

Comment: Possibly worth looking into: https://github.com/CHH/php-build

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041511/how-to-compile-php-extensions-cross-version (short answer, you can't do this in one binary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try a hybrid approach. Compile your C++ library separately and then create an open source PHP extension wrapper for that. The PHP extension has nearly no logic of its own. It converts data types from PHP to C/C++ back and forth and passes the arguments to functions/methods implemented in your C++ library.

You then just maintain a binary version of your library per platform and the adoption to a particular PHP version is done by the open source PHP extension.

This of course requires that the systems of your customers do have the PHP development packages installed, as well as a compiler.

Comment: This may actually work.  Most of my clients are comfortable getting sources off the web and running make.  Thanks!  Great answer!

Comment: (Almost 4 years later) I've used this solution for about two years but then ran into the problem of the static library being incompatible across different gcc versions and OS's. So I switched to shipping source code. Which is also not ideal because C++ compilers do differ. But at least compiler errors are easier to understand and fix than "some obscure symbol not found" errors.